# Seekbar issue in media notification

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

**This is my showNotification Function in my android app. When I am launching the app notification is showing but the icons are not coming and when im deleting the code for seekbar in showNotification then the seekbar is not working but the icons are showing and also working.**

```js
fun showNotification(playPauseBtn:Int){
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("songs")
            .document(PlayerActivity.SongList[PlayerActivity.songPosition]).get()
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                val song = it.toObject(SongModel::class.java)
                song?.apply {
                    val intent = Intent(baseContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                    val flag = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
                    } else {
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    }
                    val contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this@MusicService, 0, intent, flag)
                    val prevIntent = Intent(baseContext, NotificationReceiver::class.java).setAction(ApplicationClass.PREVIOUS)
                    val prevPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(baseContext, 0, prevIntent, flag)
                    val playIntent = Intent(baseContext, NotificationReceiver::class.java).setAction(ApplicationClass.PLAY)
                    val playPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(baseContext, 0, playIntent, flag)
                    val nextIntent = Intent(baseContext, NotificationReceiver::class.java).setAction(ApplicationClass.NEXT)
                    val nextPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(baseContext, 0, nextIntent, flag)
                    val exitIntent = Intent(baseContext, NotificationReceiver::class.java).setAction(ApplicationClass.EXIT)
                    val exitPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(baseContext, 0, exitIntent, flag)
                    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
                        val playbackSpeed = if(PlayerActivity.isPlaying) 1F else 0F
                        mediaSession.setMetadata(MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
                            .putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, mediaPlayer!!.duration.toLong())
                            .build())
                        mediaSession.setPlaybackState(PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                            .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING, mediaPlayer!!.currentPosition.toLong(), playbackSpeed)
                            .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SEEK_TO)
                            .build())
                        mediaSession.setCallback(object: MediaSessionCompat.Callback(){
                            override fun onSeekTo(pos: Long) {
                                super.onSeekTo(pos)
                                mediaPlayer!!.seekTo(pos.toInt())
                                val playBackStateNew = PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
                                    .setState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING, mediaPlayer!!.currentPosition.toLong(), playbackSpeed)
                                    .setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SEEK_TO)
                                    .build()
                                mediaSession.setPlaybackState(playBackStateNew)
                            }
                        })

                        val notification = androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(baseContext, ApplicationClass.CHANNEL_ID)
                            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                            .setContentTitle(title)
                            .setContentText(subtitle)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.music_icon)
                            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.logo))
                            .setStyle(androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle().setMediaSession(mediaSession.sessionToken))
                            .setPriority(androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                            .setVisibility(androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                            .addAction(R.drawable.previous_icon, "Previous", prevPendingIntent)
                            .addAction(playPauseBtn, "Play", playPendingIntent)
                            .addAction(R.drawable.next_icon, "Next", nextPendingIntent)
                            .addAction(R.drawable.exit_icon, "Exit", exitPendingIntent)
                            .build()
                        startForeground(13, notification)
                    }

                }
            }
```